# Error using rnpm

Tags: node.js, npm

After installing rnpm, I tried to use it to install a package

```
rnpm install react-native-in-app-utils
```

and received the following error message

```
/usr/local/lib/node_modules/rnpm/bin/cli:11
updateNotifier({ pkg }).notify();
                     ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token }
```

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`rnpm` requires node version 4.1, but I was running an earlier version. I following [these instructions](http://tecadmin.net/upgrade-nodejs-via-npm/) to upgrade node, though I am running a Mac with El Capitan and needed to do the final  symlink to `/usr/local/bin/node` rather than `/usr/bin/node`.